# Kivy not working Error - [CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, android, kivy

> I am new to Kivy and I try to run this code
>
> ```
> # Set window provider before importing other Kivy modules Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'visible')
> Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400') Config.set('graphics',
> 'height', '200') Config.set('graphics', 'window_backend', 'x11')
>
> Config.write()
>
> from kivy.app import App from kivy.uix.button import Button from
> kivy.uix.label import Label from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
>
>
> class MyApp(App):
>     def build(self):
>         layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
>
>         self.label = Label(text='Hello, Kivy!')
>         layout.add_widget(self.label)
>
>         self.button = Button(text='Click me!')
>         self.button.bind(on_press=self.on_button_click)
>         layout.add_widget(self.button)
>
>         return layout
>
>     def on_button_click(self, instance):
>         self.label.text = 'Button clicked!'
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     MyApp().run()
> ```
>
> i tried also to install it from github and a diffrent ways  when i run
> this code i get this error

```
> C:\Users\Administrator\env\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\project.py 
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Administrator\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-02-18_55.txt
> [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
> [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
> [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
> [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Administrator\env\Scripts\python.exe"
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
> [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
> [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
> [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
> sdl2 - ValueError: angle_sd12 is not a recognized GL backend
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
> cls = cls()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 165, in __init__
> super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1129, in __init__
> self.create_window()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 361, in create_window
> super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1495, in create_window
> self.initialize_gl()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1465, in initialize_gl
> init_gl(allowed=self.gl_backends_allowed,
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\gl\__init__.py", line 45, in init_gl
> gl_init_symbols(allowed, ignored)
> File "kivy\\graphics\\opengl.pyx", line 1556, in kivy.graphics.opengl.gl_init_symbols
> File "kivy\\graphics\\cgl.pyx", line 113, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_init
> 
> [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

> iam using PyCharm and i installed this pkgs with all ways that i could
> do  [my packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLLgL.png) i also try to
> run it on vs code and manually without IDE  and tried to uninstall all
> this pkgs and reinstall them and nothing change